# I wnt to connect php and mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$host ="localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "StuDet";

$conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db,$conn);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Unable to select database");


?>
```

I have a doubt in line "$conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);"

Comment: Avoid the pain now at this early stage and begin using `mysqli` rather than the deprecated `mysql` functions

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: start using `mysqli` inside of depreciated mysql or opt for PDO

Comment: what is your doubt? we aren't mind readers so we can not know your doubts. have you ran the code? did you get any errors or warnings?

Comment: refer it mysql deprecated from php now http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: @TharuKasthuriArachchi well, you are getting this error because mysql_* functions are deprecated. So start using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: yeah I got a error I paste it here Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\my\MyFirst\connt.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\my\MyFirst\signUp.php(2): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\my\MyFirst\connt.php on line 7

Comment: Strongly recommend that you stop using `@` to suppress / ignore errors, solve them instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$host ="localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "StuDet";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

// Check connection
if (!$con){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Try the above code. Use **mysqli**.

Comment: Even better: PDO.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct. If no connection is made, check your credentials and db name.

Also, since mysql is deprecated, change to mysqli.

link http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php